# Search query in url

Tags: javascript, php, .htaccess

I'm currently working on a project almost like steamrep.com but for another game and more features.
I know basic php js etc but there is 1 thing i can't seem to understand.
And that is when you for ex search for

```
     yourdomain.com/profiles/ (any id / username)
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make it so it takes the givin id / username puts it as a variable and display it on a page.

If anyone could give me a lead that would be verry much appreciated!

EDIT: To clear up the question. I want to take the id or username from the url and display it the page as a variable.

Comment: Are you trying to grab the variable in JavaScript or PHP? I assume the latter?

Comment: There are many different ways of displaying part of the current URL on the page. One way is with JavaScript: assuming a numerical ID, `let id = location.href.match(/profiles\/(\d+)/)[1];` then display `id`. Though, if you want to display other contents that depend on the ID, a server-side implementation may be more appropriate. It all depends on what you’re trying to do.

Comment: I'm trying todo something like steamrep.com. I would use an api to load in names and data i can do all this but when they search for mydomain.com/profiles/ (any id) it has to take that id and display it on the page.